# Hiding preferences items in the settings bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings, settings-bundle

Just a question i've been stuck on for a while. I would like the user to be allowed to hide some settings found on the Root.plist.

Anybody know if this is possible? failing this is it possible to essentially have two Root.plist files and swap between the two depending upon a variable? Please let me know if there is fundamentaly anything wrong with what I am try to achieve.

Thanks for your help :)

ps/ Alternatively could I be able to "grey-out" options within the app settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot do this. Settings keys are static and cannot be changed after compilation.

You might consider creating a "Settings" screen manually within your app.

Comment: Just to clarify for everybody it is not possible to do any of the actions I suggested in the question. The only option is to create an in-app settings page.

Answer (score 4):

You can have an element only appear on an iPad or iPhone+iPod. To do this add a:

`SupportedUserInterfaceIdioms` key, that holds an array of supported idioms-strings, either "`Pad`" or "`Phone`". Including “Phone” will display the element on iPhone and iPod touch; including “Pad” will display it on iPad. Including both values will display it on both devices.